# Add font responsiveness

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, responsive

I have a custom section created for my WP page. You may find CSS and HTML here: http://www.cssdesk.com/J469A

Everything works fine but for the responsiveness of the font. If you shrink the size of the browser, you will see that the font size remains the same and the text does not fit into the box.

I tried using font-size: 100% , but it does not help.

You may have a look here: http://www.sflsupport.org/programs/ It's the very last section (Webinar Archive)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

font is not responsive, try using em units to make font responsive.  try looking at [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-responsive-web-design-how-to-manage-fonts/)

Pay attention that in the site that you published all the squares, except the last one, are images, that is why you may think that the font is responsive.